# Prepare for skydiving or extreme sports

Tags: sports

Is there a way to train yourself for skydiving if you have vertigo?

Like progressive steps with other sports or activities that start training you for it, so skydiving is not such a big change. Has anyone done it?

Comment: Are you confusing vertigo with fear of heights? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acrophobia  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertigo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like gliding, skydiving is really not a sport that vertigo affects - you are so far removed from the ground that it doesn't make you wobble. I have trouble going near the edge of a cliff, or even near a window if I am more than a couple of floors upas I have vertigo, but can happily fly a glider, with no panic.

So don't worry about preparing for the vertigo aspect. Training instead is focused on the steps you need to do safely, and when.

Comment: It's conditioning. At the school, you'll learn how to land safely (legs, back, head position, etc.). The succession of heights to 'hop' off will start at a few feet and increase. Take them as you come to them. Stop whenever you want - it's not a race. Enjoy. I'm with Rory.